# Unable to center dynamic content with react-slick

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, slick.js, react-slick

I am trying to implement a carousel that expands the centered item to show more content.
Currently I have this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-slick-center-whnkj5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A33%2C1). However I am unable to center the slide as its pushed to the left and it randomly pushes it to the right upon further scrolling. I have tried the solutions suggested in [this ticket](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/648) as well as modifying the paddings and margins in the `.slick-track` and `.slick-list` to no avail.

At the moment it looks like this:
[image: Current implementation]

Comment: your sandbox is not accessible

Comment: Updated the sandbox permission